# How to Hide Field from Order Create From Back-end Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders

I have to Hide Some of the Fields from shipping and Billing Adress how I can achieve this need guidance thank you

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Step-1**

please open the file **Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Address.php** and check there is **_prepareForm** method please add below 2 lines and override the block

```
protected function _prepareForm()
  {
   '''''''''''''''''''''
   $attributes = $addressForm->getAttributes();
   unset($attributes['prefix']);
   unset($attributes['suffix']);
   .........................
}
```

**I hope this is helpful to you!!**

Comment: But unable to override this file, can you please tell at which layout file this block file class mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are after remove a field?

Add a plugin for the Model `Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="layout_checkout_process" type="Mbs\ModuleName\Plugin\CheckoutLayoutProcess" />
    </type>
</config>
```

the plugin like below:

```
<?php
use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class CheckoutLayoutProcess
{
    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function afterProcess(LayoutProcessor $subject, $jsLayout)
    {
        $fieldNameToRemove = 'firstname';

        unset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'][$fieldNameToRemove]);

        if ($this->isBillingOnPaymentPage()) {
            unset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']
                ['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']['children'][$fieldNameToRemove]);
        } else {
            $configuration = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'];
            foreach ($configuration as $paymentGroup => $groupConfig) {
                if (isset($groupConfig['component']) and $groupConfig['component'] === 'Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address') {
                    unset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                        ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$paymentGroup]['children']['form-fields']['children'][$fieldNameToRemove]);
                }
            }
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }

    private function isBillingOnPaymentPage()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('checkout/options/display_billing_address_on');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove a field from **customer_form_attribute** Table

SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_id` = 537

**SELECT * FROM `customer_form_attribute` WHERE `attribute_id` = 537**

Image Reference -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F8R2.png

You need to remove the ***form_code*** base on your requirement after
cache clean and flush.

***Note: this solution work for me.***