# How to remove the visibility for customer address attribute field while creating order in magento backend

Tags: orders, backend, magento2.3.3, create-order, address-attribute

I wish to delete customer  address attribute  in create order section in Magento backend

I have tried to override the following file to unset the attribute before rendering. For testing purpose, I have edited the core file and unset the attribute from

```
protected function _prepareForm()
```

vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Form/Address.php

It works fine in core file, but when I override this file using preference, I am unable to override the file, can anyone suggest me to override this

I have tried based on this [How to Hide Field from Order Create From Back-end Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316061/how-to-hide-field-from-order-create-from-back-end-magento-2)

Comment: Kindly check your module sequence in /etc/module.xml

Answer (score 1):

Checklist:

- Check if your module is enable: bin/magento module:status
- Add the sequence (Magento_Sales) like explained here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html
- Make sure you run bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: Magento_ Sales module also mentioned in sequence in my custom module module.xml