# customize the address form in Magento 2 to display only one field for the address in admin panel

Tags: magento2

[image: only in admin panel i want to show only field to add the address right now there are two fields. How i can achieve it?]

only in admin panel i want to show only field to add the address right now there are two fields. How i can achieve it?

Comment: Do you still want to see 2 fields on the customer side ?

Comment: yes that's the functionality i want show only one field on admin side and other than that let everything stay as it is

Comment: As this fields are editable, how will you tell which part belong to which street_line ? Do you want them separated by some delimiter ?

Comment: yes that would be great

Comment: Hello @Harris please try this way https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316061/how-to-hide-field-from-order-create-from-back-end-magento-2/316177#316177

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with css.

just put below css in the admin area.

```
input[name="street[1]"] {
    display: none;
}
```

You can add above css by using an extension or by creating child admin theme.

Comment: i dont have much knowledge of magento can you tell me where i need to create a file in which dir . i am asuming it should be in app/desing/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/adminhtml/whats next